# angular-slick transclude not working in dynamic ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I have the code below using angular-slick. fevt keeps changing on swipe over first slick carousel.

```
<slick  slides-to-scroll="1" arrows="false" current-index="slick.current"  class="first-slide"  on-after-change="slick.onAfterChange(this)">
    <div ng-repeat="s in evt">
    </div>
</slick>

<slick  slides-to-scroll="{{numtoslide}}"  init-onload=true data="fevt" arrows="false" variable-width="true" center-padding="60px" center-mode="false">
    <div ng-repeat="t in fevt" ng-if="t.section != 'venues'" style="width:320px;margin-right:5px;" >
   </div>
</slick>
```

about.js

```
$scope.slick = { current:0, init : function(){}, goto : function(index)   {this.current = index}, next : function(index){return this.current++}, prev : function(index){this.current--}, onBeforeChange : function(){}, onAfterChange : function(){} }

$scope.slick.onAfterChange = function(e){   
    $scope.fevt = [];
    for(var j=0; j< $localStorage.eventlist[0].items.length; j++){
        if($localStorage.eventlist[0].items[j].related_venue == $scope.test){
            $scope.fevt.push($localStorage.eventlist[0].items[j]);
        }
    }       
    $scope.$apply();                    
}
```

slick.js

```
if (scope.initOnload) {
    isInitialized = false;
    return scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != null) {
            return $transclude(function (clone, scope) {
                var compiled;
                if (isInitialized) {
                    destroySlick();
                }
            compiled = $compile(clone)(scope);
            element.append(compiled);

            initializeSlick();
            return isInitialized = true;
        });
    }else{
        isInitialized = false;
        initializeSlick();
    }
});
} else {
    return $transclude(function (clone, scope) {
        var compiled;
        compiled = $compile(clone)(scope);
        element.append(compiled);
        return initializeSlick();
    });
}
```

When swipe over with afterchange event there is newval detected but secound carousel doesnt update based on new array

Any help appreciated Thanks

Comment: Any help been stuck for 3 days now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find solution so i change way to make it work.

I combined slick and flexi sider to achieve the things i want.

Slick loads first slider and afterChange function fires event and creates new array for used in ng-repeat and flexi will generated new silder every time there is swipe in first slider.

Thanks